# fullScreenCover Dismiss with Drag SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui, drag, dismiss, dismissviewcontroller, draggesture

Is it possible to dismiss a View with a scroll view by dragging down when in .fullScreenCover? I know .sheets can, but can it be done with fullScreenCover? I very new at swift.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.